# Difficulty Creating an S3 Bucket ACL using Terraform

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I have used both my root account and an IAM User, yet I am finding it hard to create an ACL for my bucket. The below code is for my IAM User.

```
resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "s3_full_access" {
  name       = "s3_full_access_attachment"
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess"
  users      = ["iamadmin"]
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "My_bucket" {
  bucket = "my-test-bucket-for-vpc-endpoints"
  tags = {
    Name = "My bucket"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "my_bucket_acl" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.My_bucket.bucket
  acl    = "public-read"
}

resource "aws_s3_object" "object" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.My_bucket.bucket
  key    = "curl.txt"
  source = "curl.txt"
  acl    = "public-read"

  etag = filemd5("curl.txt")
}
```

The error I keep getting

```
│ Error: error creating S3 bucket ACL for my-test-bucket-for-vpc-endpoints: AccessDenied: Access Denied
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the iam policy and bucket policy resource, then added a bucket policy, and public access block resource.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "My_bucket" {
  bucket = "my-test-bucket-for-vpc-endpoints"
  tags = {
    Name = "My bucket"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_object" "object" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.My_bucket.bucket
  key    = "curl.txt"
  source = "curl.txt"

  etag = filemd5("curl.txt")
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "example" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.My_bucket.bucket

  block_public_acls       = false
  block_public_policy     = false
  ignore_public_acls      = false
  restrict_public_buckets = false
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "bucket_policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.My_bucket.bucket

  # Terraform's "jsonencode" function converts a
  # Terraform expression's result to valid JSON syntax.
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Id      = "MYBUCKETPOLICY"
    Statement = [
      {
        Sid       = "PublicReadGetObject"
        Effect    = "Allow"
        Principal = "*"
        Action    = [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ]
        Resource = [
          "${aws_s3_bucket.My_bucket.arn}/*",
        ]
      },
    ]
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise against using `aws_iam_policy_attachment`. See the warning in the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_policy_attachment):

> The aws_iam_policy_attachment resource creates exclusive attachments
> of IAM policies. Across the entire AWS account, all of the
> users/roles/groups to which a single policy is attached must be
> declared by a single aws_iam_policy_attachment resource.

Attaching that policy would mean any other permissions are removed. Use `aws_iam_user_policy_attachment` or `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment` instead.

Comment: How does a user policy resource differ from a bucket policy resource?

Comment: Read the documentation I linked above

Comment: okay, I just did. It's amazing how they all differ. It's clear now. I also decided to use a bucket policy. Then I added a public access block and removed the bucket acl block, then it worked.